# How to show entered text as Combobox selected item when "IsEditable" is true in UWP ComboBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uwp, combobox, uwp-xaml

I want to create a ComboBox + TextBox and for this I tried to set "IsEditable" true in ComboBox.
I'm using a collection of objects in as ItemSource for ComboBox which is working fine. But when I enter any text it shows me this error.

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ComboBoxOption' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1'.  Exception thrown:'System.NullReferenceException' in CBExample2.exe

I think this error is because when I enter text in combobox it takes it as a string which is not converted back to object.

Here is my full code.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ComboBoxItemConvert x:Key="ComboBoxItemConvert" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox"
                  DisplayMemberPath="ComboBoxHumanReadableOption"
                  Header="ComboBox"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboBoxOptions}"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedComboBoxOption, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ComboBoxItemConvert}}"
                  SelectedValuePath="ComboBoxOption" />
        <TextBlock Name="BoundTextblock" Text="{x:Bind SelectedComboBoxOption.ComboBoxHumanReadableOption, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The code behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> ComboBoxOptions;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ComboBoxOptions = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
        ComboBoxOptionsManager.GetComboBoxList(ComboBoxOptions);
        SelectedComboBoxOption = ComboBoxOptions[0];
    }

    public class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public string ComboBoxOption { get; set; }
        public string ComboBoxHumanReadableOption { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComboBoxOptionsManager
    {
        public static void GetComboBoxList(ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> ComboBoxItems)
        {
            var allItems = getComboBoxItems();
            ComboBoxItems.Clear();
            allItems.ForEach(p => ComboBoxItems.Add(p));
        }

        private static List<ComboBoxItem> getComboBoxItems()
        {
            var items = new List<ComboBoxItem>();

            items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "Option1", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "Option 1" });
            items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "Option2", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "Option 2" });
            items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "Option3", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "Option 3" });

            return items;
        }
    }

    ComboBoxItem _SelectedComboBoxOption ;
    public ComboBoxItem SelectedComboBoxOption
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedComboBoxOption;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedComboBoxOption != value)
            {
                _SelectedComboBoxOption = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedComboBoxOption");
            }
        }
    }

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
}
```

And the converter class

```
public class ComboBoxItemConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value.GetType().Equals(typeof(ComboBoxItem)))
        {
            return value;
        }
        return new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "new", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "new" }; 

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value as MainPage.ComboBoxItem;
    }
}
```

What I want is to add the entered text as the new option in combobox which should be treated as selected when entered. 
Please help. I'm stuck at this point for past 4 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that the converter does not consider the case of `null`.

Please follow the steps below:

1. Removed the definitions of the `ComboBoxItem` and `ComboBoxOptionsManager` classes from the `MainPage` and defined them separately.
2. Override `ComboBoxItem`'s Equal method to handle subsequent item additions

```cs
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string ComboBoxOption { get; set; }
    public string ComboBoxHumanReadableOption { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is ComboBoxItem item &&
               ComboBoxOption == item.ComboBoxOption;
    }
}
```

3. Modify the structure of `ComboBoxItemConvert` and add a dataset

```cs
public class ComboBoxItemConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> Options { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value !=null && value.GetType().Equals(typeof(ComboBoxItem)))
        {
            return value;
        }
        var newItem = new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = "new", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = "new" };
        if(Options!=null && !Options.Contains(newItem))
        {
            Options.Add(newItem);
        }
        return newItem;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value as ComboBoxItem;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```xml
<local:ComboBoxItemConvert x:Key="ComboBoxItemConvert" Options="{x:Bind ComboBoxOptions}" />
```

When you enter an item that is not in the default data set (`ComboBoxOptions`) and press `Enter`, a new `ComboBoxItem` is added to the data set as the selected item.

---

If you need to enter custom text and generate new entries accordingly, you need to add something new.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private string _editText;
public string EditText
{
    get => _editText;
    set { _editText = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EditText"); }
}
```

**Converter**

```cs
...
public string ComboBoxEditText { get; set; }
...
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    ...
    var newItem = new ComboBoxItem() { ComboBoxOption = ComboBoxEditText ?? "new", ComboBoxHumanReadableOption = ComboBoxEditText ?? "new" };
    if (Options != null && !Options.Contains(newItem))
    {
        Options.Add(newItem);
    }
    return newItem;
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ComboBoxItemConvert x:Key="ComboBoxItemConvert" Options="{x:Bind ComboBoxOptions}" ComboBoxEditText="{x:Bind EditText,Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Page.Resources>

...
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox"
      ...
      IsEditable="True"
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
      Text="{x:Bind EditText,Mode=TwoWay}"
      ...
      />
...
```

This will fulfill your requirements.

Best regards.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but it doesn't seems to be working. One only once change I noticed is that whenever I select the any option first time, it is being added to the list. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you override the `ComboBoxItem.Equal` method correctly? Also, can you describe your steps? I can't reproduce this problem here

Comment: The steps which I followed  :
Created a separate class file to create `ComboBoxItem` and `ComboBoxOptionsManager` class.
Updated the code of `ComboBoxItemConvert`.
Modified the `MainPage.xaml` and it code behind as per your suggestions.

Can you please take a look at my code and guide me where I'm going wrong.
Here is the [link to code](https://github.com/ced-mohitp/comboboxEx/tree/master/CBExample2)

Comment: Hi, I checked your code, please replace the `SelectedValue` binding in your `Combo` with `SelectedItem`. `SelectedValue` points to a property of the data model you selected (`ComboBoxOption` in your project, which is a string), and your `Converter` returns a `ComboBoxItem` class. Type mismatch causes conversion problems

Comment: Made the changes and finally it worked !! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Hi, I need a bit help again.
In my real project I need to create a listivew and this `ComboBox` will be in each of the list view item. In this scenario how should I set the `converter` properties as those properties will not be accessible inside the `datatemplate` of listview item.
I hope I'm able my problem to you. Any suggestions for that ?  How should I proceed further. I thought of binding them as `converterparameters` but I found that we can not bind them.

Comment: Hi, maybe this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334681/uwp-xaml-add-data-binding-outside-datatemplate) can help you. You can create a `ViewModel`, then put the Collection and variables in it. At XAML code, you can bind the `ViewModel` as 
ListView's `DataContext`. In `DataTemplate`, you can use `{Binding ElementName=your_list_view, Path=DataContext.xxx}` to bound data. If this does not match your actual situation, please ask a new question instead of following up on unrelated questions