# How to create ComboBox + TextBox in a ListView and add entered text as new item in ComboBox

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, combobox, viewmodel

I want to create a `ListView` in which I need to create a `ComboBox` in each list view item.
That `ComboBox` should be editable so that it will accept the text and create a new item with entered text. I some what achieved that taking reference of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368381/how-to-show-entered-text-as-combobox-selected-item-when-iseditable-is-true-in/59369504?noredirect=1#comment104993112_59369504)

Here is the code of MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:RoleConverter x:Key="RoleConverter" Options="{x:Bind VM.UserRoleList}" RoleEditText="{x:Bind VM.EditText,Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="DataListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind UserList}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:User">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind username}" Width="150" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind fisrt_name}"  Width="150"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind last_name}"  Width="150" />
                    <ComboBox 
                        Width="150"
                        IsEditable="True"
                        IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                        Text="{Binding ElementName=DataListView, Path=DataContext.EditText, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="name"
                        SelectedItem="{x:Bind user_role, Mode=TwoWay , Converter={StaticResource RoleConverter}}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataListView, Path=DataContext.UserRoleList,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </ComboBox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind user_role.name , Mode=OneWay}"  Width="150"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="submit" Click="submit_Click" Content="click" />
</Grid>
```

Now the problem is I've set the converter class properties as global so when I enter text in one list item it reflect in other items as well.
[image]
It should change the text in the row in which it is entered. Here is my the complete [source code](https://github.com/ced-mohitp/ComboBoxEx3)

Please help ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the problem is I've set the converter class properties as global so when I enter text in one list item it reflect in other items as well.

The problem is `Text` bind the same value, if you edit the source, all ComboBoxs Text property will be change as well. For your requirement, you could process in `ComboBoxs` class. we need custom  `ComboBox` and listen `TextSubmitted` event. And I have edit your project, please refer the following code.

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        this.Loaded += MyComboBox_Loaded;
    }

    private void MyComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextSubmitted += MyComboBox_TextSubmitted;
    }

    private void MyComboBox_TextSubmitted(ComboBox sender, ComboBoxTextSubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        var items = ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<UserRole>;
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (items.Any<UserRole>(s => s.name == args.Text))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var newItem = new UserRole() { id = (items.Count + 1).ToString(), name = args.Text };
                items.Add(newItem);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml Code without Converter**

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
        x:Name="DataListView"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind UserList}"
        >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:User">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{x:Bind username}" />
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{x:Bind fisrt_name}" />
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{x:Bind last_name}" />
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{x:Bind user_role.name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <local:MyComboBox
                        Width="150"
                        DisplayMemberPath="name"
                        IsEditable="True"
                        IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataListView, Path=DataContext.UserRoleList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedItem="{x:Bind user_role, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button
        Name="submit"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Click="submit_Click"
        Content="click"
        />
</Grid>
```